# What does objc_autoreleaseReturnValue mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a method `createATestObject`. As its name indicates, it create an object and return it. The code is very simple and it is under ARC.

```
- (TestObj *)createATestObj
{
    return [[TestObj alloc] init] ;
}
```

I assembly the file and get the assembly code below.

```
Lfunc_begin4:
    .cfi_startproc
@ BB#0:
    push    {r7, lr}
    mov r7, sp
    sub sp, #8
    @DEBUG_VALUE: -[ViewController createATestObj]:self <- undef
    @DEBUG_VALUE: -[ViewController createATestObj]:_cmd <- undef
    str r0, [sp, #4]
    str r1, [sp]
    movw    r0, :lower16:(L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_-(LPC4_0+4))
    movt    r0, :upper16:(L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_-(LPC4_0+4))
LPC4_0:
    add r0, pc
    ldr r0, [r0]
    movw    r1, :lower16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_10-(LPC4_1+4))
    movt    r1, :upper16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_10-(LPC4_1+4))
LPC4_1:
    add r1, pc
    ldr r1, [r1]
    blx _objc_msgSend
    movw    r1, :lower16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_-(LPC4_2+4))
    movt    r1, :upper16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_-(LPC4_2+4))
LPC4_2:
    add r1, pc
    ldr r1, [r1]
    blx _objc_msgSend
    add sp, #8
    pop.w   {r7, lr}
    b.w _objc_autoreleaseReturnValue
Ltmp13:
Lfunc_end4:
    .cfi_endproc
```

I noticed the function `_objc_autoreleaseReturnValue` and get the reference about it from [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-runtime-objc-autorelease). But I didn't know what it means. Can anyone elaborate it ? Thanks very much.

> id objc_autoreleaseReturnValue(id value);
>
> Precondition: value is null or a pointer to a valid object.
>
> If value is null, this call has no effect. Otherwise, it makes a best
>   effort to hand off ownership of a retain count on the object to a call
>   to objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue for the same object in an
>   enclosing call frame. If this is not possible, the object is
>   autoreleased as above.
>
> Always returns value.

Comment: It's an optimization that avoids adding the returned object to the autorelease pool when both the caller and callee are ARC-aware. More info is here: http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/75082194868/arcs-fast-autorelease

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @Darren first, thanks for your link.

I reference some paragraph in the [link](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/75082194868/arcs-fast-autorelease).

> ARC has a trick that keeps returned objects out of autorelease pools
>   if both the caller and callee are ARC.
>
> But how does that work? One of
>   the features of ARC is that old compiled-before-ARC code (MRC code)
>   can call ARC code and vice-versa. But if ARC code doesn’t put a
>   returned object in an autorelease pool that MRC code is expecting,
>   then the object would just leak.
>
> So ARC-ified clang code emits this
>   function call when returning an object:
>   objc_autoreleaseReturnValue(id).
>
> If you look at
>   objc_autoreleaseReturnValue's [implementation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm), it calls
>   callerAcceptsFastAutorelease(). Even if you don’t read x86_64 or ARM
>   assembly, the code’s comment is straight-forward:

```
/*
  Fast handling of returned autoreleased values.
  The caller and callee cooperate to keep the returned object 
  out of the autorelease pool.

  Caller:
    ret = callee();
    objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue(ret);
    // use ret here

  Callee:
    // compute ret
    [ret retain];
    return objc_autoreleaseReturnValue(ret);

  objc_autoreleaseReturnValue() examines the caller's instructions following
  the return. If the caller's instructions immediately call
  objc_autoreleaseReturnValue, then the callee omits the -autorelease and saves
  the result in thread-local storage. If the caller does not look like it
  cooperates, then the callee calls -autorelease as usual.

  objc_autoreleaseReturnValue checks if the returned value is the same as the
  one in thread-local storage. If it is, the value is used directly. If not,
  the value is assumed to be truly autoreleased and is retained again.  In
  either case, the caller now has a retained reference to the value.

  Tagged pointer objects do participate in the fast autorelease scheme, 
  because it saves message sends. They are not entered in the autorelease 
  pool in the slow case.
*/
```

**Something From me**

Let's see the source code of `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue`.

```
id 
objc_autoreleaseReturnValue(id obj)
{
#if SUPPORT_RETURN_AUTORELEASE
    assert(tls_get_direct(AUTORELEASE_POOL_RECLAIM_KEY) == NULL);

    if (callerAcceptsFastAutorelease(__builtin_return_address(0))) {
        tls_set_direct(AUTORELEASE_POOL_RECLAIM_KEY, obj);
        return obj;
    }
#endif

    return objc_autorelease(obj);
}
```

`__builtin_return_address(0)` [returns the return address of current function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html), then let's look at the `callerAcceptsFastAutorelease`'s implementation for arm version:

```
static bool callerAcceptsFastAutorelease(const void *ra)
{
    // if the low bit is set, we're returning to thumb mode
    if ((uintptr_t)ra & 1) {
        // 3f 46          mov r7, r7
        // we mask off the low bit via subtraction
        if (*(uint16_t *)((uint8_t *)ra - 1) == 0x463f) {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        // 07 70 a0 e1    mov r7, r7
        if (*(uint32_t *)ra == 0xe1a07007) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the method, it looks for the instruction `mov r7, r7` which is a marker for `objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue`, if it find that, then the method return `true`, so callee will omit the autorelease.

You can see the assembly code of caller which is `testFun1` in my case.

```
- (void)testFun1:(ViewController *)vc
{
    [vc createATestObj] ;
}
```

Below is the assembly code, you can find the line "mov  r7, r7      @ marker for objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue"

```
    .cfi_startproc
@ BB#0:
    push    {r7, lr}
    mov r7, sp
    sub sp, #16
    add r3, sp, #4
    movw    r9, #0
    movt    r9, #0
    str r0, [sp, #12]
    str r1, [sp, #8]
    str.w   r9, [sp, #4]
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r2
    bl  _objc_storeStrong
    movw    r0, :lower16:(L_objc_msgSend$non_lazy_ptr-(LPC5_0+4))
    movt    r0, :upper16:(L_objc_msgSend$non_lazy_ptr-(LPC5_0+4))
LPC5_0:
    add r0, pc
    ldr r0, [r0]
    movw    r1, :lower16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_12-(LPC5_1+4))
    movt    r1, :upper16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_12-(LPC5_1+4))
LPC5_1:
    add r1, pc
Ltmp14:
    ldr r2, [sp, #4]
    ldr r1, [r1]
    str r0, [sp]                @ 4-byte Spill
    mov r0, r2
    ldr r2, [sp]                @ 4-byte Reload
    blx r2
    @ InlineAsm Start
    mov r7, r7      @ marker for objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue
    .code   16
    @ InlineAsm End
    bl  _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
    bl  _objc_release
    movs    r1, #0
    movt    r1, #0
    add r0, sp, #4
    bl  _objc_storeStrong
    add sp, #16
    pop {r7, pc}
Ltmp15:
Lfunc_end5:
    .cfi_endproc
```

**Update:**

I think there are some mistakes in comments of [apple's implementation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm).

The correct comment should be like this:

```
/*
  Fast handling of returned autoreleased values.
  The caller and callee cooperate to keep the returned object 
  out of the autorelease pool.

  Caller:
    ret = callee();
    objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue(ret);
    // use ret here

  Callee:
    // compute ret
    [ret retain];
    return objc_autoreleaseReturnValue(ret);

  objc_autoreleaseReturnValue() examines the caller's instructions following
  the return. If the caller's instructions immediately call
  objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue, then the callee omits the -autorelease and saves
  the result in thread-local storage. If the caller does not look like it
  cooperates, then the callee calls -autorelease as usual.

  objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue checks if the returned value is the same as the
  one in thread-local storage. If it is, the value is used directly. If not,
  the value is assumed to be truly autoreleased and is retained again.  In
  either case, the caller now has a retained reference to the value.

  Tagged pointer objects do participate in the fast autorelease scheme, 
  because it saves message sends. They are not entered in the autorelease 
  pool in the slow case.
*/
```

Leave a comment if you have other ideas. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, I don't think it's `callerAcceptsFastAutorelease` anymore. I think it's `callerAcceptsOptimizedReturn` called by `prepareOptimizedReturn` in https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/master/runtime/objc-object.h.